# Servos: attach() and write()

Tags: arduino-ide, servo, pwm, sketch

Arduino newbie here, so this question might sound too simple. I am trying to run a parallax continuous rotation servo using Arduino Uno. From the reference, I learned that the servo needs to be "attached" to one of digital pins with PWM capability, and the servo's speed can be controlled by `write(0~180, 90=stop)`.

But I am having a hard time understanding the role of the PWM digital pin. If the servo's speed and direction of rotation is determined by `write()`, what is the role of `attach(pin#)`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`attach` tells the servo library which pin it should be writing to, this is stored somewhere in ram and `write` will look it up and communicate with the correct pin.

It's possible that you are using the other pwm capable pins for other purposes and suddenly having that library interfere with that is not a good thing.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you don't need to connect it to one of the PWM pins. Any digital output pin will work just fine.

Judging by the Arduino reference, attaching the servo to a pin is kind of like to declare a variable. By using `myservo.attach(pin)` you also give the servo a name (myservo in this case), and you can also add maximum and minimum values to the servo's rotation by adding two extra values to the end: `myservo.attach(pin, min, max)`

When you then use the `myservo.write()` function, the Arduino will "remember" what pin myservo is connected to, as well as the maximum/minimum settings for it.

Comment: Servos need the pwm on the control line, they compare the duty cycle value to the internal potentiometer and apply torque to correct any discrepancy

Comment: @ratchetfreak yes, but what I meant is that you don't have to use one of the pins with PWM labeled onto them. On the Arduino Uno, pin 3, 5, 6, 9, 10 and 11 are PWM pins, but you don't have to use one of these.